# PyQt5 : close window on right click sends the event to application underneath as well

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mouseevent, desktop-application

I have this app where I was trying to close window on right click event, although the event works and my window is closed but the right click is also sent to the app that is present below my python app and therefore a context menu(if present) is opened for that app.

For eg, if I have windows desktop screen below my python app, the context menu of windows will be opened.

[image]

This is what I have tried

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
import sys

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow): 
    
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        
        self.setWindowFlag(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(qtc.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.showFullScreen()
        self.setAttribute(qtc.Qt.WA_NoMousePropagation)

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = qtg.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(qtg.QPen(qtc.Qt.blue, 1))
        qp.drawRect(self.rect())
        
        qp.setOpacity(0.01)
        qp.setPen(qtc.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(self.palette().window())
        qp.drawRect(self.rect())

    # close on right click
    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == qtc.Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Left Button Clicked")
        elif QMouseEvent.button() == qtc.Qt.RightButton:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have tried using WA_NoMousePropagation but that is also not working.

```
OS: Windows 10
PyQt5==5.15.6
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.9.0
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on linux. However, you might be able to fix it on your system by using the context-menu signal instead. So, in `MainWindow.__init__`, add these two lines: `self.setContextMenuPolicy(qtc.Qt.CustomContextMenu); self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.close)`. And also remove the mouse-press event handler.

Comment: Could you please explain what its doing and why not use the mouse event handler?

Comment: See the Qt5 Docs: [contextMenuPolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#contextMenuPolicy-prop). A mouse-press event is not the same as a context-menu event, so handling it may not stop the propagation of an explicit context-menu event. Did you try my suggestion? As I say, I can't actually reproduce the issue on linux, so I'm not able to test it myself.

Comment: yes I tried your suggestion and it worked.

Comment: If you add a `contextMenuEvent` handler (without setting the context-menu policy), you should see that a right-click will deliver both a mouse-press event and a context-menu event. On my system, the mouse-press event is delivered first, and calling `close()` afterwards does not stop the following context-menu event. This suggests a possible alternative solution might be to do `self.setContextMenuPolicy(qtc.Qt.NoContextMenu)`, and then handle the mouse-press event as before. This should kill all context-menu events for the main-window.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either, but in case the alternative solution suggested by ekhumoro doesn't work, you could try another possibility: `QTimer.singleShot(0, self.close)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro I tried adding `self.setContextMenuPolicy(qtc.Qt.NoContextMenu)` but it did ot work for me on windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On right click of the mouse 2 of the events that gets fired are `OnMousePress` and `OnMouseRelease`. Most of the desktop apps and the dektop screen as well responds to the `OnMouseRelease` event. And since I am closing the window on `mousePressEvent`. The window is closed but the release event is sent to the application underneath the window. And hence we are seeing the context menu on the application below our app.

Closing on `mouseReleaseEvent` worked for me.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg
import sys

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow): 
    
    def __init__(self, *arg, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*arg, **kwargs)
        
        self.setWindowFlag(qtc.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(qtc.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.showFullScreen()

        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = qtg.QPainter(self)
        qp.setPen(qtg.QPen(qtc.Qt.blue, 1))
        qp.drawRect(self.rect())
        
        qp.setOpacity(0.01)
        qp.setPen(qtc.Qt.NoPen)
        qp.setBrush(self.palette().window())
        qp.drawRect(self.rect())

    # close on right click
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == qtc.Qt.RightButton:
            self.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```